# Red-Green light indicators in C# .NET Form

Tags: c#, winforms

What's the quickest way to show a red/green light indicator on a C# form?

I originally thought about using radio buttons, but not sure how to set the color of the dot, only the foreground/background text.

Then I thought about drawing a circle.  Couldn't find a toolbox shape for that, and didn't want to write code just to draw the circle.

Basically, I'm writing a little application specific monitor, that shows a red light if certain services are down, or certain web services are not responding.

This is what I have so far using a square button instead of a circle.  The code is just what I want, I just want a round shape.

```
        if (allGood)
        {
            btnIISIndicator.BackColor = Color.Green; 
        }
        else
        {
            btnIISIndicator.BackColor = Color.Red; 
        }
```

Answer (score 24):

This is simple, just use `System.Windows.Shapes` for the object and `System.Windows.Media.Brushes` for the colors.

For a circle you can do the following:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse circle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse();
circle.Height = 20; //or some size
circle.Width = 20; //height and width is the same for a circle
circle.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

Then you can make a function to do your check for red and green.

Also, you can use hex values for the colors as well:

```
circle.Fill = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#RRGGBB"));
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer which provides a way how to do it without fixed images. This is especially useful if e.g. the colour comes from a settings file.

Comment: Don't forget to add a reference to `PresentationFramework` and `PresentationCore` if you are building a WinForms app.

Answer (score 3):

I would just make a panel or `PictureBox` and set the Background image to that of a red/green light.  Either make the images in PhotoShop/PaintShop/MS Paint or download some stock images off the web.

Whenever the status changes, just swap the image out.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly related to the question at hand, but your code could be shortened somewhat using the ternary operator as such:

```
btnIISIndicator.BackColor = allGood ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
```

But that all depends on your (or your organization's) definition of readability and maintainability.

Comment: Good point, I know ternary operator, but typically forget to code it.

Answer (score 2):

just try this it works for me.

```
SolidColorBrush solidColor=new SolidColorBrush();
  solidColor.Color=Colors.Red;
 ellips_circle.Fill=solidColor;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I was finding solution very similar you provide...

Answer (score 1):

I just use some standard images and put them in a `picturebox`. works great on our apps.

Answer (score 1):

Create red and green bitmaps and use the `PictureBox` control to show the bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

Use an image, but theres some great icons available [here](http://www.famfamfam.com/) so you dont have to actually make some.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used a non enabled button as indicator since I did not manage to install the WinUI for shapes. Same suggestion as question but simplified.

```
    indicatorButton.Enabled = false;

    ...

    if (allGood)
    {
        indicatorButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
        indicatorButton.Text = "On";
    }
    else
    {
        indicatorButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
        indicatorButton.Text = "Off";
    }
```